# Extracting information from a string and converting that to a column for further use in python pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, feature-extraction

This is the dataset that I'm working on

```
Sr. No. Product                Rate Offered
0   1   Beige Glossy                 100
1   2   BLACK TEXTURE                100
2   3   New Black Matt               100
3   4   PP Euro Grey Satin           100
4   5   PP Light Grey S/g (AAH)      100
```

I want extract features out of the Product column 
Like the PP in 4th and 5th row is Pure Polyester Chemistry

I was able to break the string with `new = data["Product"].str.split(" ", n = 5, expand = True)` 
And I get some thing like this

```
       0      1       2      3       4
0   Beige   Glossy  None    None    None
1   BLACK  TEXTURE  None    None    None
2   New     Black   Matt    None    None
3   PP      Euro    Grey    Satin   None
4   PP      Light   Grey    S/g    (AAH)
```

I also gave the names to these new columns with this `new.columns =['First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth']`

```
    First  Second   Third   Fourth  Fifth
0   Beige   Glossy  None    None    None
1   BLACK   TEXTURE None    None    None
```

So I want to make a new column like this.So I use 
`filter = new.First=='PP'
new.insert(5,"Chemistry","PP")
new.where(filter,inplace=True) 
new`

```
    First Second Third Fourth Fifth Chemistry
0   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
3   PP    Euro   Grey  Satin  None  PP
4   PP    Light  Grey  S/g   (AAH)  PP
```

This kills all the other rows which are not PP

Comment: Use `new.Chemistry = new.Chemistry.where(filter)`

Comment: Used this `new.Chemistry = new.Chemistry.where(filter)` but I get an error            
 `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Chemistry'`